# Excel VBA find a text string from folder files and get relative data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder with lots of excel files inside. I need to search the contents of these files according to predefined keywords and once any of these keywords is found I need to extract some data from the table (since I have managed to get the most of the data, here I need help only in getting the data from the last row of the second to the next cell). After that, I have to make a list of all found data in another table. My search table looks something like this: (Header cells and 2 empty cells next to them are merged in my excel table as well as "kg", "m3" and "TN" cells)

| Sand |  |  | Big Stone |  |  | Metal |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| kg |  |  | m3 |  |  | TN |  |  |
| Norm | Act. | Approved | Norm | Act. | Approved | Norm | Act. | Approved |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0.2 | 2.69 | 2.69 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | 1.19 | 4.74 | 4.74 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | 0.02 | 0.07 | 0.07 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| X |  | 47.2 | X |  | **14.9** | X |  | 0.07 |

I have to find a cell that contains a word "stone" and get the value from the last row of "Approved" column i.e. "14.9" and put it in my other table in which I am listing all found values. My other table looks like the below example:

| Keyword | Workbook | Worksheet | Address | Found cell content | Measure | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stone | D:\Inert\М-29.xlsm | M-29 | $W$2 | Big Stone | m3 | 14.9 |

I actually have got a code from the internet to do the task and adapted it to my case. Unfortunately, as I have very little knowledge of VBA, I was not able figure out how to get "Amount" column value (just this one). In my case, these values should have been listed in G column of newly created final table. Below is my code, the part of the code that is necessary to be corrected is highlighted with "??????" question marks. I use MS Office 365. Any help is really appreciated. Thank you!

```
    Public Sub searchText()
    Dim MyFSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim MyFolder As folder
    Dim MySubfolder As folder
    Dim wb As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    searchList = Array("stone", "somthng")    'define the list of text you want to search, case insensitive
    
    Set MyFSO = New FileSystemObject
    folderPath = "D:\Inert\М-29.xlsm" 'define the path of the folder that contains the workbooks
    Set folder = MyFSO.GetFolder(folderPath)
    Dim thisWbWs, newWS As Worksheet
    
    'Create summary worksheet if not exist
    For Each thisWbWs In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wsExists("summary") Then
            counter = 1
        End If
    Next thisWbWs
    
    If counter = 0 Then
        Set newWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        With newWS
            .Name = "summary"
            .Range("A1").Value = "Keyword"
            .Range("B1").Value = "Workbook"
            .Range("C1").Value = "Worksheet"
            .Range("D1").Value = "Address"
            .Range("E1").Value = "Found cell content"
            .Range("F1").Value = "Measure"
            .Range("G1").Value = "Amount"
        End With
    End If

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    End With
        
    'Check each workbook in main folder
    For Each wb In folder.Files
        If Right(wb.Name, 3) = "xls" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsm" Then
            Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open(wb)
            For Each ws In masterWB.Worksheets
              For Each Rng In ws.UsedRange
                For Each i In searchList
                    If InStr(1, Rng.Value, i, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then   'vbTextCompare means case insensitive.
                        nextRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        
                        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary")
                            .Range("A" & nextRow).Value = i
                            .Range("B" & nextRow).Value = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
                            .Range("C" & nextRow).Value = ws.Name
                            .Range("D" & nextRow).Value = Rng.Address
                            .Range("E" & nextRow).Value = Rng.Value
                            .Range("F" & nextRow).Value = Rng.Offset(1).Value
                            .Range("G" & nextRow).Value = ??????????????
                        End With
                    End If
                Next i
              Next Rng
            Next ws
            ActiveWorkbook.Close True
        End If
    Next
    
    'Check each workbook in sub folders
    For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
        For Each wb In subfolder.Files
            If Right(wb.Name, 3) = "xls" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsm" Then
                Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open(wb)
                For Each ws In masterWB.Worksheets
                  For Each Rng In ws.UsedRange
                    For Each i In searchList
                        If InStr(1, Rng.Value, i, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                            nextRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary")
                                .Range("A" & nextRow).Value = i
                                .Range("B" & nextRow).Value = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
                                .Range("C" & nextRow).Value = ws.Name
                                .Range("D" & nextRow).Value = Rng.Address
                                .Range("E" & nextRow).Value = Rng.Value
                                .Range("F" & nextRow).Value = Rng.Offset(1).Value
                .Range("G" & nextRow).Value = ??????????????
                            End With
                        End If
                    Next i
                  Next Rng
                Next ws
                ActiveWorkbook.Close True
            End If
        Next
    Next
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .AskToUpdateLinks = True
    End With
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary").Cells.Select
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary").Range("A1").Select
    
End Sub 

Function wsExists(wksName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    wsExists = CBool(Len(Worksheets(wksName).Name) > 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: `ws.Cells(Rows.Count, Rng.Column + 2).End(xlUp).Value` would be the last non-empty cell  value in the column two columns over from `Rng`

Comment: @Tim Williams, thank you very much! Just this part was missing from the code. It brilliantly accomplished the task!